# Laravel 5.6 validation unique rule (advancement) as per user base

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have following table schema.

```
     Schema::create('wallets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('opening_balance', 10, 2)->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('active')->default(true);
        $table->integer('sort')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

I am using form requests for my project as under.
I have WalletStoreRequest.php and WalletUpdateRequest.php as following.

**WalletStoreRequest.php**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'           => 'required|unique:wallets,
        'code'            => 'required',
        'opening_balance' => 'required',
        'active'          => 'required|numeric',
        'sort'            => 'required|numeric',
    ];
}
```

**WalletUpdateRequest.php**

```
public function rules()
{
    $id = \Request::segment(4);
    return [
        'title'           => 'required|unique:wallets,id,' . $id,
        'code'            => 'required',
        'opening_balance' => 'required',
        'active'          => 'required|numeric',
        'sort'            => 'required|numeric',
    ];
}
```

I want a validation on per user basis system, like every user can have a same name wallet example named "cash" in title column but if a user creates new wallet again with the name "cash" validation should say you have it already.

More explanation:

**User A:**

1. Cash
2. Bank ABC
3. Debit Card
4. Etc

**User B:**

1. Cash *(Same title as USER A has) ALLOWED*
2. Bank XYZ
3. Credit Card
4. Cash *(Should not be allowed again) NOT-ALLOWED*

What would be the rules for title field? please guide best practice for both situation store and update.

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the there will always be a logged in user you could do something like:

**WalletStoreRequest.php**

```
'title' => 'required|unique:wallets,title,NULL,id,user_id,'. $this->user()->id,
```

**WalletUpdateRequest.php**

```
'title' => 'required|unique:wallets,title' . $id . ',id,user_id,' . $this->user()->id,
```

The unique string is broken down in to a few sections:

- `wallet,title`: This is the name of the table and the column.
- `$id .',id'`: This is the value and column name of what can be ignored (essentially a `where not`)
- `user_id,' . $this->user()->id`: This is the column name and value of what has to match in the row (essentially a where clause). You can keep chaining as many of these on as you want.

If you're using Laravel >=5.3, you can use the `Rule` class:

```
'title' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('wallets', 'title')->ignore($id)->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', $this->user()->id);
    })
]
```

You will need to add the `use` statement for the `Rule` class into your Request class:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique) for more information

---

You could easily merge your 2 request classes in to one with something like:

```
return [
    'title'           => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('wallets', 'title')->ignore(optional($this->route('wallet'))->id)->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', $this->user()->id);
        }),
    ],
    'code'            => 'required',
    'opening_balance' => 'required',
    'active'          => 'required|numeric',
    'sort'            => 'required|numeric',
];
```

The above is using the [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional) helper method. The above also assumes that you're using implicit model binding and the variable is called `wallet`.

Comment: I think you should rename id after wallets to title

Comment: 'title' => 'required|unique:wallets,title,NULL,id,user_id,'. $this->user()->id,

Comment: And can you please explain it in your own words, because I wasn't able to find it in the documentation easily.

Comment: @zarpio I've add a bit of a breakdown to my answer. Let me know if you want more clarification.

Comment: Your brief explanation would be great because I have another situation as you can see I have the soft-delete option if a user deletes his wallet and create again with the same title it should allowed :-(

Comment: @zarpio For that you would add on something like `deleted_at,NULL` to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

```
'title' => Rule::unique('wallets')->where(function ($query) use ($id) {
    return $query->where('user_id', $id);
})
```

It is always nice to use the `Rule` reference on complex rules.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique

A tiny side note:

If you url looks like this: `/some/path/to/{id}`

You might wanna consider doing `$this->route('id')` to retrieve the parameter from url.